# PERL WCF Web Service Call Fails

Tags: perl, web-services, wcf, soap, lwp-useragent

I am making web service calls using PERL to one of our vendor provided web services.  The web services use SOAP 1.2 and WSHttpBinding.

I am able to make calls successfully to most of the calls in the web service, except for the RetrieveReport call.  The RetrieveReport call is supposed to stream a file.  However I am getting the response below.

An example to call the RetrieveReport was provided using C# code mentioning to use the following binding.  However I have no clue how to do this in PERL.  If anyone can provide any assistance, I thank you in advance.

**C# App Config Binding**

```
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_IBIStreamService" closeTimeout="00:02:00"
                    openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
```

**PERL Code**

```
my $reportKey = 'report_key';
my $reportUri = 'report_uri';

my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $userAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'https://service.com/services/BIDataService');

my $message = <<'.';
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
  <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://service.com/dataservices/bistream/2/IBIStreamService/RetrieveReport</a:Action> 
  <h:ReportKey xmlns:h="http://service.com/dataservices/bistream/2" xmlns="http://service.com/dataservices/bistream/2">[ReportKey]</h:ReportKey>
  <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">[ReportRetrievalUri]</a:To> 
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RetrieveReportRequest xmlns="http://service.com/dataservices/bistream/2" /> 
  </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
.

# Replace the dynamic values
$message =~ s/\[ReportKey\]/$reportKey/g;
$message =~ s/\[ReportRetrievalUri\]/$reportUri/g;

my $request = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $uri);

$request->header(SOAPAction => '"http://service.com/dataservices/bistream/2/IBIStreamService/RetrieveReport"');
$request->content($message);
$request->content_type("application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");

print "-- CONTENT --\n\n";
print $request->content . "\n\n";

my $response = $userAgent->request($request);

if ($response->is_success) {
    print "--SUCCESS--\n" . $response->decoded_content . "\n";
} else {
    print "--FAILURE--\n" . $response->status_line, "\n";
    print $response->error_as_HTML;
}
```

**Response From Vendor**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/fault</a:Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <s:Code>
                <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
                <s:Subcode>
                    <s:Value>a:ActionNotSupported</s:Value>
                </s:Subcode>
            </s:Code>
            <s:Reason>
                <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">The message with Action \'http://service.com/dataservices/bistream/2/IBIStreamService/RetrieveReport\' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</s:Text>
            </s:Reason>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**WSDL Source**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="BIStreamService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:i0="http://service.com/dataservices/bistream/2" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IBIStreamService_policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsdl:import namespace="http://service.com/dataservices/bistream/2" location="https://service.com/services/BIStreamingService?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
    <wsdl:types/>
    <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_IBIStreamService" type="i0:IBIStreamService">
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IBIStreamService_policy"/>
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="RetrieveReport">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://service.com/dataservices/bistream/2/IBIStreamService/RetrieveReport" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="RetrieveReportRequest">
                <soap12:header message="i0:RetrieveReportRequest_Headers" part="ReportKey" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="StreamReportResponse">
                <soap12:header message="i0:StreamReportResponse_Headers" part="Status" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="i0:StreamReportResponse_Headers" part="StatusMessage" use="literal"/>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IBIStreamService" type="i0:IBIStreamService">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="RetrieveReport">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://service.com/dataservices/bistream/2/IBIStreamService/RetrieveReport" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="RetrieveReportRequest">
                <soap:header message="i0:RetrieveReportRequest_Headers" part="ReportKey" use="literal"/>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="StreamReportResponse">
                <soap:header message="i0:StreamReportResponse_Headers" part="Status" use="literal"/>
                <soap:header message="i0:StreamReportResponse_Headers" part="StatusMessage" use="literal"/>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="BIStreamService">
        <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IBIStreamService" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_IBIStreamService">
            <soap12:address location="https://service.com/services/BIStreamingService"/>
            <wsa10:EndpointReference>
                <wsa10:Address>https://service.com/services/BIStreamingService</wsa10:Address>
            </wsa10:EndpointReference>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IBIStreamService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IBIStreamService">
            <soap:address location="https://service.com/services/BIStreamingService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Doing SOAP by hand with just LWP is very hard work. Why don't you use [XML::Compile::WSDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-Compile-WSDL11/lib/XML/Compile/WSDL11.pod) or [SOAP::Lite](http://p3rl.org/SOAP::Lite) instead?

Comment: I had several issues installing XML::Compile::WSDL.  I tried SOAP::Lite but the vendor web services are very customized and I had a tough time getting it to work properly with SOAP::Lite.  It is easier to provide the full XML code, submit it and parse it with LWP.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue.

There are two URLs for the report web service.  One to execute the report and a different one to retrieve the report.  I modified the LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => '') and the HTTP::Request->new(POST => '') to both point to https://service.com/services/BIStreamingService when retrieving the report and now it works.

Thank you!